# TokenValidationParameters no longer working after upgrade to 5.0.0

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I have the following code which was working when I was using 
**System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=4.0.20622.1351**

```
private static void ConfigureAzureAD(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    appBuilder.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
        new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
            TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
            }
        });
}
```

However as soon as I upgraded this package to the latest one which is [version 5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/) it no longer compiles complaining 
Reference to type 'TokenValidationParameters' claims it is defined in System.IdentityModel.Token.Jwt but it could not be found.

Also if you try the following compiler will warn you that **Audience is obsolete**:

```
 private static void ConfigureAzureAD(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        appBuilder.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
            });
    }
```

I downgraded this DLL again and used  the version 4.0.20622.1351, it started compiling.

Has there been a syntax change for Configuring the Azure Active Directory?

On Github I could not find a single project using the latest package 5.0.0 and all of them are using the previous package 4.0.20622.1351. Can anyone shed some light on this using the latest **System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 5.0.0** or direct me to some project on Github using the latest package?

Comment: Had the same problem. Looking at https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet it seems that 5.0 is only for ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 30):

TokenValidationParameters is in assembly: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens

It looks like you are using Katana (the first version of asp.net OWIN offering).
Katana does not support 5.0.0. You need to stick with 4.x.

The latest version of asp.net takes a dependency on S.IM.xx and M.IM.xxx 5.0.
https://github.com/aspnet

Comment: That's not the answer to the question. Problem is fully clear and I am looking for some fix. I don't care in which assembly that TokenValidationParameters is. I expect the code to be working when I upgrade the package.

Comment: @MHOOS. You need to know in which assembly TVP is present if you are doing this `new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters` in your code. Also, its a major version upgrade and there are breaking changes as explained here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#major-changes-from-4x. Samples can be found here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=aspnetcore

Comment: Also, it seems you are using Katana. That does not support 5.x.

Comment: @brent-schmaltz and @ezile I think you're missing the point. Nuget reports that v5.0.0 is an upgrade to v4.0.2.x. But a) there is no link to project info in order to discover the changelog.md (most packages have such a link), b) it's more than a breaking change; it's a "you need to move your entire platform over if you want to update this package" change, c) you can set the Nuget package to require "not any later than version X" dependencies, and d) may I introduce you to the `System.ObsoleteAttribute` decoration? It's been in .NET since 1.0. It's really helpful in cases like this.

Comment: @ezile - Yeah, there's a problem with the samples.  They reference the 4.0.0 version of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.  If you upgrade to 5.1.2, the sample (e.g. active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation) crashes.

Comment: I agree, this is a fairly big fail on Microsoft's part.  This is clearly not bringing the package forward, but a different paradigm altogether.  It's unfortunate that they didn't separate the namespaces and create a separate set of classes.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with Katana.  I'm constructing a fresh MVC 4 Win API service and have run into the exact same problem.

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury If you're using the OWIN packages with Web API, it's Katana. It's not well-documented that's the case, though.

Comment: Does anyone know if a fix for this is on its way, or if MS is just ignoring the problem?

Comment: This is diabolical.  Just ran into this issue using OWIN 3.1, having added a reference to the Twilio nuget package, and finding that my `TokenValidationParameters` is no longer working.  Let's hope that the OWIN 4.0 Preview is in a good state.

Comment: The accepted answer today should be @Nate Barbettini's as the released Katana components can be made to work with some minor namespace changes https://stackoverflow.com/a/45851021/11635 IMO

Comment: What is Katana? Literally NONE of any of these packages related to Owin or JWT have the word Katana in them.  Also, shouldn't NuGet enforce package dependencies so that this doesn't happen? Like... if you update a package from v4 to v5, that shouldn't break everything. It should force the upgrade of dependent packages so they continue to work.

Answer (score 20):

**Short version:** Make sure you use version 4.0 or later of the Microsoft.Owin packages, such as [Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt).

---

As the other answers mentioned, there was a breaking change in [System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt) from version 4.0 to 5.0. This caused problems because some packages like [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols/) depended on version 5.0, while older Katana/OWIN packages like [Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt) were still hardcoded to depend on version 4.0.

The good news is that this is [being fixed](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/7) in the new Katana 4.0 release. The 4.0 packages (such as [Jwt](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt) and [Cookies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies)) have been published to NuGet as prerelease packages and will be available as stable packages soon.

Comment: We dropped IdentityModel 5.2.0-preview1 with Katana 4.0-alpha1 on nuget.org. See: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/4.0.0-alpha1 and https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens/5.2.0-preview1-408290725

Comment: @BrentSchmaltz Nice, excited to see those 4.0 packages making progress towards stable! Updated my answer.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque released on Feb 19

Comment: I just pulled the latest versions available on NuGet and this fails. Not sure why. I didn't chose 4 or 5, simply accepted whatever latest (non-prerelease) was offered to me.

Comment: @NitinSingh There might be an existing package in your project that is requesting the 4.0 version.

Comment: The existing references built just 1.5 month back were having compiling code, now when a new dev checks out the branch and update all packages, he is unable to build... We are wondering if packages change like that, what will happen to code in production when we have to deploy a hot fix... Things like this will delay वे too long than the solution development

Answer (score 7):

I don't know when or if this will ever be fixed, but I hope it will.  I've already posted these issues on the [Github site](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/466) for the AAD extensions and on the [Katana site](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/464). You can follow along with the discussions and progress on those sites, and if you care to, you can always post your interest in seeing this addressed.

I can't understand how this was not seen as an issue before release.  "Upgrade to .Net Core" is not a reasonable solution.  My app has no chance of doing that for a good while, as do most non-trivial projects.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need to upgrade to M.IM 5.0? S.IM 4.x is a supported release that works with Katana.

Comment: It's the tao of Nuget.  I like to keep my Nuget upgrades window clean.  I have sooo many Nuget items added to this project, and there are many projects that I work on, that I can't remember "oh, this item is a breaking upgrade."  If you apply it, you'll break your app.  

I think a better approach would have been to release a separate Nuget project, not as an upgrade.  Call it 5.0 or whatever, but not have it been an upgrade.  That would have been cleaner.

An upgrade may break a project, but with 5.0 there's no amount of my coding that can fix it.  So its not an upgrade; its a new product

Comment: Xhris, I hear you. We wanted to keep the packages logically together as they represent our IdentityModel for Core offering. We are fixing Katana to use the 5.x version. So, I a couple of months this will all go away.

Comment: @BrentSchmaltz, any update when Katana fix will be available?

Comment: @BrentSchmaltz, a couple of months :)

Comment: So much for this being fixed in a couple of months, it's now late January 2018 and this is still an issue.

Comment: @Justin fixed now ;) Can we upvote Nate's answer to de-emphasize this now-misleading answer please.

Comment: @BrentSchmaltz I just pulled an update and its still not working (after an year of your original comment)

Answer (score 6):

So I am also experiencing the same issue today. After looking down to the bottom of it I think I know the answer.

In short it is the issue with Katana project (http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/) being failed to comply with the current changes of Windows Azure Active Directory IdentityModel Extensions for .Net (https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet)

For more details, TokenValidationParameters was there in System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt assembly verion 4.0 but it has been moved out in version 5.0. The new home for it is now in assembly Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.

Sorry I can not provide a fix it is a design change from which the Katana code base needs to be dramatically refactored.

Comment: That is correct. We are working on a fix. We realize that this is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Katana currently will not work with the 5.x version of IdentityModel.
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet

However, there is work underway to fix this. Timeline is not set yet.

Comment: I have this issue, but don't have a package called 'Katana' installed,  Were the authors dumb enough to name the package differently from the project name??  If so, what is the name of the thing that Needs removed?   How can I get this to work with 5.1, as I don't see any sense in doing new implementations in the old/obsolete way.

Comment: It appears that 6.22 MILLION people downloaded this, and one would presume are also out of luck with their projects.  There doesn't seem to be any examples online of anyone using this updated version.  I may have to ask that question instead. :-(

Comment: Katana was a development name for a version of asp.net that use the OWIN pipeline. It is the precursor to the current asp.net Core. As an intern step, the IdentityModel libraries were modified to support Katana. The 5.x versions have .Net Standard targets. You can not use them against the shipping version of Katana. An updated version of Katana is due out shortly to fix this issue.

Comment: I am not using Katana as far as I can see. I just tried to move to dotNet Core, and stopped when I found that too much of what I need in EntityFrameworkCore is not even close to being implemented.

Comment: @BrentSchmaltz - This was last year, I worked for a different company then, sorry, I really have no idea if I got it resolved...